# jQuery $.parseJSON breaking with a valid JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

According to the image below

[image]

I'm trying to parse the (valid, according to JSONLint) JSON string with

```
obj = $parseJSON(data);
```

and receiving an error message of "Unexpected string".

Does anyone know what is the problem here?

Comment: can you show the code. the image isnt going to show how/where you call the parse method or show us the full data/json

Comment: Related: [SyntaxError: Unexpected token e on valid json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529561).

Comment: What is the `string(1092)` at the beginning? If that is part of what is trying to be parsed, that would explain the `Unexpected token s` message.

Comment: `string (1092)` is not valid json

Comment: I don’t think `string(1092)` is part of the JSON, but only some sort of console debugging output.

Comment: @Xufox it is, the last url output this entire string

Comment: Please post text, not images. The response body consists of the string, and some sort of metadata describing that string. The metadata isn't valid JSON. In addition the server is sending back `Content-Type: text/html` which would appear to be incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated there is nothing wrong with `$.parseJSON`.

It's because you are using [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to output your json server side.

so the output include also the type and the length of your variable
`string(1092) "mystring...`

You should use a simple

```php
echo $myjson;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are showing is not valid json.

There should be nothing showing outside of `[]` including the external quotes and extra characters like `"strong(1092)"`.

There is something wrong in your server output approach.

You can't selectively pull out part of the response and only validate that part.... the whole response body must validate

Answer (score 2):

It's sending back invalid JSON, and suspicious headers:

```
➜  ~  http GET http://www.borntoraiseheaven.org/categoria/lista/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 257
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 14:27:56 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze19

string(1092) "[ {"id_categoria":"188","descricao_categoria":"Envelopes"},
{"id_categoria":"187","descricao_categoria":"Tags"},
{"id_categoria":"186","descricao_categoria":null},
{"id_categoria":"184","descricao_categoria":null},
{"id_categoria":"160","descricao_categoria":"Adesivos"},
{"id_categoria":"161","descricao_categoria":null},
{"id_categoria":"183","descricao_categoria":"Postais"},
{"id_categoria":"169","descricao_categoria":"Folder\/Panfleto\/Flyer"},{"id_categoria":"158","descricao_categoria":null},
{"id_categoria":"164","descricao_categoria":"Cartazes"},
{"id_categoria":"178","descricao_categoria":null},
{"id_categoria":"166","descricao_categoria":"CD\/DVD"},
{"id_categoria":"167","descricao_categoria":"Encartes p\/ Mercados"},
{"id_categoria":"162","descricao_categoria":null},
{"id_categoria":"176","descricao_categoria":null},
{"id_categoria":"168","descricao_categoria":null},
{"id_categoria":"181","descricao_categoria":"Pastas"},
{"id_categoria":"163","descricao_categoria":null},
{"id_categoria":"182","descricao_categoria":null},
{"id_categoria":"177","descricao_categoria":"Kit de Amostras "} ]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed dot(.) In $parseJSON. You need to use $.parseJSON()

Comment: True, however, the error message indicates this is a typo in the OP, and not the underlying problem.